# How can I access custom event values from Azure AppInsights analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am reporting some custom events to Azure, within the custom event is a value being held under the customMeasurements object named 'totalTime'.

The event itself looks like this:

```
loading-time: {
    customMeasurements : { 
        totalTime: 123
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a graph of the average total time of all the events reported to azure per hour. So I need to be able to collect and average the values within the events.

I can't seem to figure out how to access the customMeasurements values from within the Azure AppInsights Analytics. Here is some of the code that Azure provided.

```
union customEvents
| where timestamp between(datetime("2019-11-10T16:00:00.000Z")..datetime("2019-11-11T16:00:00.000Z"))
| where name == "loading-time"
| summarize Ocurrences=count() by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| order by timestamp asc
| render barchart
```

This code simply counts the number of reported events within the last 24 hours and displays them per hour.

I have tried to access the customMeasurements object held in the event by doing

```
summarize Occurrences=avg(customMeasurements["totalTime"])
```

But Azure doesn't like that, so I'm doing it wrong. How can I access the values I require? I can't seem to find any documentation either.

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful to project the data from the customDimensions / customMeasurements property collecton into a new variable that you'll use for further aggregation. You'll normally need to cast the dimensions data to the expected type, using one of the *todecimal*, *toint*, *tostring* functions.

For example, I have some extra measurements on dependency telemetry, so I can do something like so

```
dependencies
| project ["ResponseCompletionTime"] = todecimal(customMeasurements.ResponseToCompletion), timestamp 
| summarize avg(ResponseCompletionTime) by bin(timestamp, 1h)
```

Your query might look something like,

```
customEvents
| where timestamp between(datetime("2019-11-10T16:00:00.000Z")..datetime("2019-11-11T16:00:00.000Z"))
| where name == "loading-time"
| project ["TotalTime"] = toint(customMeasurements.totalTime), timestamp 
| summarize avg(TotalTime) by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render barchart
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan, this worked in the way I was expecting. Can I just also ask what's the reason for the square brackets when projecting totalTime? E.g. `["TotalTime"]`. Also, I'm attempting to project a value of `email` held inside the customDimensions object by doing `extend email=tostring(customDimensions.teacherEmail)` but it's asking me to ensure that `email is indeed a simple name`, any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: the `["syntax"]` with quotes and brackets allows you to create/reference fields with special characters in the names, like `["some thing with spaces"]` or `["Period.Delimited.Name"]`.  not specifically used in this case, but good to know.